# install.js cmd hangs - unable to install Electron js npm on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, npm-install

I am a bit new to the node npm electron world and recently started developing applications related to electron js. While I am able to install and create electron application on my office system at the same time I am having issue with the personal system.

When the execute the command `npm  install electron --save-dev` the command hangs and returns no error. no error log in nodejs-log file as well.

Please help me out with this issue.

**Things that I tried are as below:**

- Some people told to remove `~/.electron` and re-install, but no luck
- Some told that it occurs due to slow internet connection speed, but mine is above 1mbps
- Some told to use `electron-prebuilt` but prebuilt is depricated and is replaced by electron
- some told to install electron globally and not locally, used `-g` but not fate
- Tried re-installation of Node on machine but same issue persist.

**Details:**

- I am using the latest version on **Node - 6.9.5** [LTS - hence node is stable]
- Version on **npm is 4.2.0**
- System is **windows 7**

**Screenshot of the command prompt execution script where the command hangs**

[image: npm install electron - node install.js hangs]

Answer (score 2):

The electron binary takes time to install and the progress bar is not shown in the quiet mode.

Try adding `--verbose` to your `npm` command to see the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Ok quick edit...

I left it to run for a bit. It then finished properly as follow:

> npm install -g electron-prebuilt
>
> npm WARN deprecated electron-prebuilt@1.4.13: electron-prebuilt has been renamed
>    to electron. For more details, see http://electron.atom.io/blog/2016/08/16/npm-
>   install-electron
>
> C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\electron -> C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\np
>   m\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\cli.js
>
> electron-prebuilt@1.4.13 postinstall C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
>   odules\electron-prebuilt
>   node install.js
>
> C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> `-- electron-prebuilt@1.4.13

I've seen on other posts that it could take a while. Unless it times out or something,i would let it do it's thing.